# Is there any possibilities to change price programmatically In app purchase android?

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I want to implement In App purchase to my application.. i have tried [this link](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/03/how-to-inegrate-in-app-purchase-billing.html#comment-form)
but this code transaction price set predefined ...Is there possible to change price.If possible means how can i change the price programmatically?.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to modify the price of the product dynamically in code. The product price is determined when we are upload our product in play store. If you want to change your product price you need to do in play store console.